# Writing Function on Data Frame in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have data in excel which have two columns 'Peak Value' & 'Label'. I want to add value in 'Label' column based on 'Peak Value' column.
So, Input looks like below

```
Peak Value 0 0 0 88 0 0 88 0 0 88 0
Label      0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
```

Input

[image]

Whenever the value in 'Peak Value' is greater than zero then it add 1 in 'Label' and replace all the zeros below it. For the next value greater than zero it should get incremented to 2 and replace all the zeros by 2.

So, the output will look like this:

```
Peak Value 0 0 0 88 0 0 88 0 0 88 0
Label      0 0 0  1 1 1  2 2 2  3 3
```

Output

[image]

and so on....

I tried writing function but I am only able to add 1 when the value is greater than 0 in 'Peak Value'.

```py
def funct(row):
    if row['Peak Value']>0:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

df['Label']= df.apply(funct, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could try using `cumsum` and `ffill`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Labels'] = (df['Peak Value'] > 0).groupby(df['Peak Value']).cumsum()
df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill().replace(np.nan, 0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    Peak Value  Labels
0            0       0
1            0       0
2            0       0
3           88       1
4            0       1
5            0       1
6           88       2
7            0       2
8            0       2
9           88       3
10           0       3
```